# SVG animation has jagged edges in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, svg

Does anyone know why this SVG animation has jagged edges in Chrome? Works just fine in Firefox.

http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/fj7Xc/

HTML:

```
<div class="svg_wrapper">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 600 425">
        <path d="M 175, 175 m 0, -75 a 75,75 0 1,0 0,150 a 75,75 0 1,0 0,-150" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="150" stroke-dasharray="0 600 600 0" stroke-dashoffset="1000">
            <animate attributeType="XML" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" from="0" to="600" dur="2s" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" />
        </path>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Chrome. It has been filed.

http://jsfiddle.net/fj7Xc/3/

The inner radius should be smooth but it looks like a stopsign.

```
<div class="svg_wrapper">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 600 425">
      <path d="M 175, 175 m 0, -75 a 75,75 0 1,0 0,150 a 75,75 0 1,0 0,-150" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="110"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```